# Find nearest email to a string in HTML

Tags: python, html, regex

I'm looking for a way to find the nearest occurrence of an email address (so either a an email in the text of the page, or an address in a mailto tag) to a certain string in an HTML document. By nearest, I mean with the fewest words in between the key string and the email.

The code I have so far:

```
import urllib,re

key_str = "King of the World"

htmlFile = urllib.urlopen("http://www.somewebsite.com")
html = htmlFile.read()

best_match = find_closest(key_str, html)
```

`find_closest()` is the function I'm not sure how to create. It should ideally return the email that is closest in terms of word distance to the first occurrence of the key_str in the html text.

I've considered using a regex to do this, but my regex skills are not up to par to complete this task. Also, the rest of my code base is in python, so a python solution is ideal for me, but I'm totally open to if any one has a better suggestion.

EDIT:

For clarification of what I'm looking for, my current use case is trying to find the email for a certain person on a directory page. So, for example, say I want to find the email for the person "email_two" in an website directory. The example HTML for the directory could look as follows:

```
...
<h2>Site Operator</h2>
<p>(555) 555-5555</p>
<h2>Email One</h2>
<p><a href="mailto:dont_email_me.admissions@test.edu">dont_email_me.admissions@test.edu</a><br>(555) 555-5555<br> 1000 Address St.<br>Ice Pole</p>
<h2>Email Two</h2>
<p><a href="mailto:email_me@test.edu">email_me@test.edu</a><br>(555) 555-5555<br>Example Place<br>Example, EX</p>
<h2>Website Feedback</h2>
...
```

If I ran `find_closest('Email Two', html)`, I hope to get email_me@test.edu.

I don't expect to be able to make a system thats right all the time, but getting the closest email to the string I'm looking for seems like the most accurate approach.

Comment: could you provide an example along with expected output? And don't parse html files with regex.

Comment: Think about how you would do it if you were manually looking for the email address.  In fact, go look at some HTML source code and do it there.  Pick a word or phrase of some kind and find the closest email in the source.  Write down the steps it took you, then break up the steps into the most basic instructions you can.  Then you can start to write the code.

Comment: @glergyl please see my updated solution, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would never parse HTML with regex, as it is not regular. I would use an XML/HTML parser like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) or [lxml](http://lxml.de/). Here is an example using my personal favorite BeautifulSoup

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def find_closest(keystr, email):
    wordList = keystr.split(' ')
    for word in wordList:
        if word.lower() in email:
            return True
    return False


key_str = "A Snowman is fun to build"

response = urllib.urlopen("http://www.builtbysnowman.com/")
htmlText = response.read()

bs = BeautifulSoup(htmlText)

emailCount = 0
for t in bs.findAll('a'):
   if (('mailto:' or '@') in t['href']) and emailCount == 0:
        closeMatch = find_closest(key_str, t['href'])
        if closeMatch:
            emailCount = emailCount + 1
            print t['href']
```

#### EDIT

As per your question edit, here is my updated solution:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def find_closest(keystr, htmlText):

    bs = BeautifulSoup(htmlText)

    emailCount = 0
    for t in bs.findAll('h2'):
        if ((t.text == keystr) and (emailCount == 0)):
            a = t.findNext('p').findNext('a')
            return a['href']


#key_str = "Email Two"

#Connect to url:

#response = urllib.urlopen("http://www.builtbysnowman.com/")
#htmlText = response.read()

htmlText = '''
<html>
    <title>
    Directory Page
    </title>
    <body>
        <h2>Site Operator</h2>
        <p>(555) 555-5555</p>
        <h2>Email One</h2>
        <p><a href="mailto:dont_email_me.admissions@test.edu">dont_email_me.admissions@test.edu</a><br>(555) 555-5555<br> 1000 Address St.<br>Ice Pole</p>

        <h2>Email Two</h2>
        <p><a href="mailto:email_me@test.edu">email_me@test.edu</a><br>(555) 555-5555<br>Example Place<br>Example, EX</p>
        <h2>Website Feedback</h2>

        <h2>Email Three</h2>
        <p><a href="mailto:email_me_sometimes@test.edu">email_me@test.edu</a><br>(555) 555-5555<br>Example Place<br>Example, EX</p>
        <h2>Website Moderator</h2>


    </body>
</html>
'''

print find_closest('Email Two', htmlText)
print find_closest('Email One', htmlText)
print find_closest('Email Three', htmlText)
```

Comment: This code checks if a word in `keystr` exists as a substring in the email.  I'm hoping to find the email that is closest (in terms of word distance) to a specific string in an HTML document.

Comment: `It should ideally return the email that is closest in terms of word distance to the first occurrence of the key_str in the html text.` Isn't very clear. So I took a stab at what you mean by that. Maybe clarification could help?